# Additive divisor problems

Tags: analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

There is plenty of literature on the binary additive divisor problem, that's evaluating
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}d(n)d(n+h)\]
for various $h$.  Why is there nothing (or I don't find) on
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}d(n)d(n+h)d(n+h')?\]
Is it too hard, too uninteresting (as in, offers nothing new after the binary case), or something else?

Comment: I would opt for "too uninteresting", but with a different meaning than you supply. There are an endless multitude of such problems that one could come up with, just jamming things together and asking "what is this"? But the ones that garner attention are the ones that come up in trying to solve important problems. What motivated you to ask think about this function? If it came about from "I had this idea about the Riemann conjecture, and this formula was involved", then it would likely gather much attention. But "Hey, how about we add another variable $h'$?" is not particularly motivating.

Comment: ye but it's not that random - whenever people look at problems with shifts or "twins of a sequence" people usually extend quite quickly to the general tuple question

Comment: @tomos: Have you already checked either the Handbook of Number Theory (Volume 1) or the Handbook of Number Theory (Volume 2)?